# ¿Se puede editar un campo de una tabla automáticamente, después que se cumpla una fecha?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

tengo una tabla que se llama ***eventos*** esta tabla tiene una columna llamada ***date*** la cual almacena la fecha cuando se realizara el evento, también tengo otra columna llamada ***status*** el cual es de tipo ENUM tiene dos opciones: 'PUBLISHED','DRAFT'.

Lo que yo quisiera hacer es que cuando la fecha que esta en ***date*** se haya cumplido entonces el evento que tiene como ***status*** 'PUBLISHED', pase entonces a estar en 'DRAFT'.

**ejemplo:** un usuario ha creado un evento para el día 10 de septiembre de 2018, cuando creo el evento puso de ***status*** 'PUBLISHED', pero ya ha pasado el tiempo, hoy es 12 de octubre de 2018, por lo tanto el status del evento ahora debería estar en 'DRAFT'.

¿Se puede programar la base de datos para que haga ese cambio automáticamente?

gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que necesitas configurar son CRON JOBS. Un Cron Job se configura en el panel del servidor y básicamente es una tarea programada que ejecutará (en este caso) un archivo PHP. 
Primero debes crear un archivo PHP que haga el UPDATE en la base de datos de todos los registros cuya fecha ya haya pasado, comparado con la fecha de "hoy" (puedes probarlo ejecutándolo directamente). Después de que tengas este archivo, vas al panel de tu servidor y generas un CRON JOB que se ejecute por ejemplo diario a las 2am, y el trabajo a ejecutar será el archivo PHP que creaste.

Puedes configurar el CRON JOB para enviarte notificaciones, y todo lo que lances a pantalla en tu archivo, te lo enviará por correo, de esa forma puedes también manejar errores y enterarte de ellos.

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, interesante respuesta... yo gestiono mis bases de datos con phpmyadmin, crees que pueda hacer eso ahí?